# facet_trelliscope does not respect ggplot2 color aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm unable to get `trelliscopejs` to respect the color aesthetic / settings from `ggplot2` when using `facet_trelliscope()`. Consider this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(trelliscopejs)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

which generates:

[image]

However, when swapping for `facet_trelliscope()`, all the colors are the same:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_trelliscope(~ cyl, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
```

[image]